# Asrock x399 Taichi - Error b2

Tags: windows, boot, hardware-failure

After turning on my Windows PC this morning, I was greeted to a blank screen. Dr Debug hangs on code 'b2' (which isn't in the manual). After waiting a while, it will boot , but the screen will then remain blank.

After some fiddling I can get into the UEFI BIOS. What is weird however, is that I flashed Ubuntu Studio onto a stick and I can get that to boot. My hardware is detected, and I can run the Unigine Valley benchmark amongst others. It seems a little slow but that may be the linux driver?

What is going on here? Am I out of the woods in terms of a hardware issue? Very much hoping it's not my GPU given the shortage!

Answer (score 1):

The B2 error code usually means Legacy ROM has an error or Graphic card problem.

Some possible measures:

- If the computer has two GPUs, one on-board, remove the other and try to boot
- Update the GPU firmware
- Try the GPU in another PCIe slot
- Try the GPU in another computer
- Replace the GPU (even temporarily)
- If the GPU seems to be fine, update the BIOS (carefully).

Comment: Thanks, I've RMAd the card and hope that will fix it. I've realised the error code may actually be an ambiguous '62'. Which implicates the mobo chipset. Will try booting without the card tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem error "b2" on my motherboard and I just pull out the screen cable from the graphics card and I run with my out screen cable. Then the error has gone and I put the cable back again and now it's running normally.